# Count Number of Times a Mouse Wheel Scroll Event has Occurred

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scroll, vb.net-2010, mousewheel

Right now, a MouseWheel scroll changes the record viewable in my DGV. A negative iDelta moves to the next record, and a positive iDelta moves to the previous record. Each record contains a header/footer and actual data in the dgv.

I'm trying to optimize the speed at which I can scroll through the records. Before I started tinkering with it, the code loads every header/footer and then loads the entire dgv of a record every time a MouseWheel Event is detected.

I'm trying to alter it to where it only loads the header/footer until the user has paused (say for ~500ms). This would ensure that unnecessary dgv aren't loaded and thus wasting time.

I've really been struggling to find either a way to count the number of times the wheel has been scrolled, a way to detect if a user hasn't scrolled the mousewheel for some amount of time, or a way to call the mousewheel scroll subroutine while still in the current mousewheel scroll subroutine. I think any of these would get me to a path of success. Here is what I have so far. Obviously, it doesn't work how I want.

```
Private Sub SplitContainer1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles SplitContainer1.MouseWheel

    Dim iDelta As Integer = e.Delta

    ' Limit the times the stopwatch restarts to every 500ms interval
    If numberOfScrolls = 0 Then
        mouseScrollStopWatch.Start()
    End If

    Select Case iButton
        Case 1, 2
            ' If iDelta is negative move to 'next' record
            If iDelta < 0 Then   

                ' If 500 ms has passed since the 'first' scroll event
                If mouseScrollStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 500 Then

                    ' Loads the header and footer of the 'next' record  
                    BindPartNumMoveNext() 

                    ' Update the dgv  
                    updateDGV()      

                   ' Reset the stopwatch            
                    mouseScrollStopWatch.Reset()

                   ' Reset number of Scrolls
                    numberOfScrolls = 0                                 

               ' If 500ms has not passed since the 'first' scroll event
                Else

                    ' Loads header and footer                           
                    BindPartNumMoveNext()  

                    ' sets number of scrolls to anything but 0     
                    numberOfScrolls = 1                                 
                End If

            ' If iDelta is positive move to 'previous' record
            Else           

                ' If 500 ms has passed since the 'first' scroll event                         
                If mouseScrollStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 500 Then 

                    ' Loads the header and footer of the 'previous' record
                    BindPartNumMovePrevious()    

                    ' Update the dgv
                    updateDGV()                  

                    ' Reset the stopwatch
                    mouseScrollStopWatch.Reset()                        

                    ' Reset number of Scrolls
                    numberOfScrolls = 0    

                ' If 500ms has not passed since the 'first' scroll event
                Else                          

                    ' Loads header and footer  
                    BindPartNumMovePrevious()           

                    ' sets number of scrolls to anything but 0
                    numberOfScrolls = 1                                 
                End If
            End If

        ' These cases can be ignored for now
        Case 3, 4                                                       
            If iDelta < 0 Then
                BindRefDesMoveNext()
            Else
                BindRefDesMovePrevious()
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

In this version of my attempts the issue is that the dgv never gets loaded if 500ms hasn't passed on that particular mousewheel scroll (i.e. if the last wheelScroll Event occurs when mouseScrollStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 500 then the dgv never gets loaded.)

Any advice on how I can capture more data from the mousewheel? The ultimate goal is just to increase the speed at which I can navigate through records so I'm open to other solutions that don't revolve around those I've outlined here.

I've tried to be specific, but I may be to close to it to realize I'm not including essential information. If I'm not, let me know and I'll include it.

Comment: Not so related to your question, but usually comments are written above the code, and not at the side. It is much easier to read it like that.

Comment: Noted @Eminem. I usually do, but Visual Studios formats comments in a way I don't like. For instance, if I tried to put comments above an 'Else' statement, Visual Studios would align the comment with the code of the preceding 'If' statement, which would make it offset. Visual Studios doesn't allow me to format my comments, but I realize now I can edit it here.

Comment: You are right. I find it annoying too. But you realy should read [this blog about comments](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-without-comments/). Im not trying to do nit picking or be cocky, but comments like `Reset number of Scrolls` and more are realy unnecessary.

Comment: I was trying to avoid unnecessary back and forth by being thorough. Which is clearly failing miserably. Once again, this is not how I would normally write my code. My coding style is actually on the other end of the spectrum of not commenting enough

Comment: If you are having problems with a large amount of data in a DGV, you might be interested in using virtual mode: [Walkthrough: Implementing Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: _comments are written above the code, and not at the side._ Sorry, but that is complete BS.

Comment: I think you need to go up a level and post about what you are doing that has brought you to this post. Navigating a DGV via scroll is not usually a problem.

Comment: @rheitzman You are correct in that navigating via scroll isn't the issue. My code will navigate through the records just fine. This is taken care of in BindPartNumMoveNext() and updateDGV(). I left the code of those functions out as it's already functional and doesn't pertain the to issue at hand. I need a way to load the header/footer on each mouse scroll, and when the user has finished scrolling (however that may be determined) then load the DGV of the corresponding record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all you need to do is use a Timer to ensure that `updateDGV()` is called when scrolling has stopped for 500 ms. I just used a textbox as the subject for scrolling and another textbox to indicate what is happening:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim scrollTimer As Timer
    Const SCROLLWAIT As Integer = 500

    Dim iButton As Integer = 1

    Private Sub SetupScrollTimer()
        scrollTimer = New Timer
        scrollTimer.Interval = SCROLLWAIT
        AddHandler scrollTimer.Tick, AddressOf FinalScroll
    End Sub

    Private Sub FinalScroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        TextBox1.AppendText("updateDGV()" & vbCrLf)
        scrollTimer.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.MouseWheel
        scrollTimer.Start()
        Dim iDelta As Integer = e.Delta

        If iDelta < 0 Then
            TextBox1.AppendText("BindPartNumMoveNext()" & vbCrLf)
        Else
            TextBox1.AppendText("BindPartNumMovePrevious()" & vbCrLf)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetupScrollTimer()

    End Sub

End Class
```

`Windows.Forms.Timer.Start()` is meant to reset the timer to zero, but there are still what appear to be spurious calls to updateDGV(). If those are a problem then you will need to adjust the code (problem left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: @ChrisSearcy You're welcome :) I have a niggling suspicion that you would be better of using a System.Timers.Timer instead to avoid the spurious calls which I found, although it may not be a problem for your UI - it might even be better for the user to see occasional extra updates. However, the principle of using a timer instead of a stopwatch remains.